# How to write conditions on/with the joined table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

There are two models Ticket and Account. account has many tickets. I am trying to get the last created ticket for each account.

```
accounts = Account.where(:deleted => false).pluck(:id)    
tickets = Ticket.left_outer_joins(:account)
    .where(:account_id => accounts)
    .order(created_at: :desc)

  ticket_ids = Array.new
  accounts.each do |account|
    ticket = tickets.where(:account_id => account).order(created_at: :desc).limit(1).first
    if !ticket.blank?
      ticket_ids.push(ticket.id)
    end
  end

  @tickets = tickets.where(:id => ticket_ids).order(created_at: :desc)
```

The above code works and @tickets contains the expected output. But the problem is the above code taking so much time. Is there any way to do all this in the fetching query itself? or Is there any way to optimize it?

Database I am using: Mysql

Comment: An optimized query might depend on the database you use (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) and if you use a sequential id (integer) or random values like (UUID). Please provide these details. Furthermore, it looks like you do not only want to have the ticket per account, there are other tables and conditions in play (admin, ticket status), please clarify.

Comment: @spickermann Question updated. I haven't used UUID in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to solve this with a subquery.

```
ticket_ids = Ticket
  .select('MAX(tickets.id)')
  .joins(:account)
  .where(accounts: { deleted: false })
  .group(account_id)

@tickets = Tickets
  .where(id: ticket_ids).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ticket_ids = Ticket.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(&:account_id).values
@tickets = Ticket.where(id: ticket_ids)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.